# Stop Render of Reactjs Component?

Tags: reactjs

I am wondering what is best practice. Should you let all components render or should you stop them from rendering? Say I have a delete modal that only gets shown on a click.

Should I put in my render of my modal

```
render() {
  // if something return false to stop rendering
  return ( )
}
```

Comment: The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#render) says "You can also return null or false to indicate that you don't want anything rendered. Behind the scenes, React renders a <noscript> tag to work with our current diffing algorithm". So, seems like it's fine to return false rather than rendering an invisible placeholder yourself.

Comment: I am not 100% on 'best practice' but I commonly see if/else checks inside JSX code to render based on conditions of your app. https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html for official docs.

Comment: Yes. What you have is exactly what you should do.

Answer (score 5):

Design your `DeleteModal` component so that in its `render()` method it renders the required UI, always. Then in the parent component, the one that uses the dialog, you conditionally show/hide it:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            some content here
            ...

            {showDeleteModal ? <DeleteModal /> : null}          
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This is the proper way to handle this i guess.